# Inner products equality for one of vectors fixed

Tags: linear-algebra

Is is true that 
$$ z \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n, \langle u,z\rangle = \langle v,z\rangle \implies u = v $$ i.e. if two inner products with fixed vector $ z $ are equal so that $ u $ and $ v $ are equals.

Comment: Why don't you use a "cross" to denote the cross product? i.e $u \times z$ instead of $<u,z>$. It's not a suggestion ; I'm really wondering why you do that.

Comment: And a more subtle question: why $<u,z>$ instead of $\langle u,z \rangle$? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For cross products, the answer is "no".

However, based on your notation, and the fact that you're talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^3$ (cross product defined specifically for $n=3$), it seems you may actually be asking about the inner product.

In that case, the answer is still "no".

Comment: You can provide counter-examples to support your claim.

Comment: @Artem: For the cross product, let $z = (1,0,0)$ and $u = (a,1,0)$, $v = (b,1,0)$ for any $a \ne b$. For the dot product, let $z = (1,0,0)$ and $u = (1,a,b)$, $v = (1,c,d)$ for $(a,b)\ne(c,d)$.

Comment: @RahulNarain seems it is you who should get a credit for an answer. Are there any conditions to be imposed on $u$ and $v$ so that implication would be true?

Comment: @Artem: Seeing as you still fail to clarify whether you mean the cross product or the inner product, I cannot answer your question.

Comment: @RahulNarain the inner product. I did the edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, they may not equal. Since vectors have directions. If the angle between u and z is $\theta_1$
$\langle u, z\rangle=|u||z|cos(\theta_1)$
the angle between v and z is $\theta_2$
$\langle v, z\rangle=|v||z|cos(\theta_2)$

Any two vectors satisfy $|u|cos(\theta_1)=|v|cos(\theta_2)$ will satisfy $\langle u, z\rangle=\langle v, z\rangle$

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

If $\langle v,z \rangle = \langle u,z \rangle$ for all $z \in V$ then you can certainly pick $z=v$ or $z=u$. Plugging this to get:

$$ \langle v,v \rangle = \langle v,u \rangle = \langle u,u \rangle. $$

From here you can rearrange:

$$ \langle v,v-u \rangle = 0, $$

which is true only if $v=u$.